# Icon is not displaying in iOS app build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created an config.xml file with following preferences for app,then i build the app using phonegap build. In iOS 6 and iOS 7 icon is not showing what mentioned in config.

Here is my config code

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.9.0" />          
    <preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />        
    <preference name="target-device"              value="ios" /> 
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />     
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="false" />           
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />

<icon src="assets/img/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="assets/img/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
```

Can any one give me any solution for this issue.

Comment: look all good to me, try using default icon tag and check what happens `<icon src="icon.png" />`, btw the icon sizes you have specified are for iOS7 only? are you testing on iOS7 ? i dont see `<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />` in your config

Comment: Thanks @krisrak,default icon tag solves my problem

Comment: add icon sizes 57 and 114, that may also solve

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup here using xcode.

[image]